# Node.js: Facebook returns me undefined instead of profile?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I want to make a **Google** and **Facebook** authentication on my application. I am using `AngularJS` on my front-end and `node.js` on my server.

Here is my Facebook authentication function on my `node.js` server:

```
var User = require('./user.js'),
    request = require('request'),
    env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    config = require('./config.js')[env],
    createSendToken = require('./jwt.js'),
    qs = require('querystring');

module.exports = function (req, res) {
    var accessTokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
    var graphApiUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me';

    var params = {
        client_id: req.body.clientId,
        redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri,
        client_secret: config.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        code: req.body.code
    };

    console.log(req.body.code);

    request.get({
        url: accessTokenUrl,
        qs: params
    }, function (err, response, accessToken) {
        accessToken = qs.parse(accessToken);

        request.get({
            url: graphApiUrl,
            qs: accessToken,
            json: true
        }, function (err, response, profile) {
            User.findOne({
                facebookId: profile.id // <-- fails here 
            }, function (err, existingUser) {

                if (existingUser)
                    return createSendToken(existingUser, res);

                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.facebookId = profile.id;
                newUser.displayName = profile.name;
                newUser.email = profile.email;
                newUser.save(function (err) {
                    createSendToken(newUser, res);
                })

            })
        });
    });
}
```

Then assigns to this `post`:

```
app.post('/auth/facebook', facebookAuth);
```

Front-end is working correctly ( I'm using `satellizer` ).

I did almost the same thing with **Google+** and it works fine but with **Facebook** it isn't.

My Facebook app is configured correctly ( I have added `http://localhost:3030/` to website URL and mobile website URL ).

Now when I run my app and press Facebook button, I get the following error on the server:

```
                            facebookId: profile.id
                                               ^
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

So that means that `profile` is `undefined`:

```
}, function (err, response, profile) {
```

Why did Facebook returned me an undefined profile?

**How can I fix that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `err` in

```
        json: true
    }, function (err, response, profile) {
        User.findOne({
            facebookId: profile.id // <-- fails here
```

to answer your question